# MongoDB match with expr+gt+lt of a field with value in array of string

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

```
{
prediction:{
        B-experience:["5"]    
           }
       }
```

Here,I need to find the B-experience is  greater than and less than by some min and max values.In my document B-experience is in array of string. So i have to convert that array string in to int and aggregate  match by expr with "gt" and "lt". I have tried with so many methods. But not getting desired result. Can some could help me out.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/UFbNEhRuMML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$arrayElemAt` to get the string out of the array, and `$toInt` in order to cast the string to int.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      predictionBexperience: {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$prediction.B-experience",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      predictionBexperience: {
        "$toInt": "$predictionBexperience"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      predictionBexperience: {
        $gt: 2,
        $lte: 7
      }
    }
  }
])
```

As can be seen on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e4bqfFokno3)  with some more sample data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its worked for me. I have one more doubt.I need full text search for two different fields in a collection. As I know, Mongocompass wont allow to text search for two fields in a single collection. So I created duplicate collection and added text search index for two fields in separate collections. So i need to write a query based on text for two fields. How can i use two text search of two collections in a single query.

Comment: You can use a `$lookup` to join these two collections, but the issue of full text search index is an issue for another question. It sound like there should be better solutions

Comment: Yes, but I m giving scoring for those two fields. For scoring, Only option I know is full text search. Is there any other solution I can get sir?

Comment: Hi sir,  please look in to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72710360/update-or-insert-an-object-inside-an-array-of-arraydouble-push