# Update or insert an object inside an array of array(double push)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

My initial one  of the document in a collection will be:

```
{
Canditate:"Clark weg",
Location:"California",
Education:"Graguate"
Match_Tasks:[]
}
```

I am getting response as a iteration in my code like:
1 st iteration response:

```
{
Asignee:"Mike@gmail.com",
Task_ID:"ObjectID_(2)"
}
```

After the 1st iteration response, My updated document is like:

```
{
Canditate:"Clark weg",
Location:"California",
Education:"Graguate"
Match_Tasks:[{Asignee:"Mike@gmail.com", 
        Task_ID's:
            [
            {ID:"ObjectID_(2)"}
            ]
        }
}
```

2 nd iteration response:

```
{
Asignee:"Scarlett@gmail.com",
Task_ID:"ObjectID_(3)"
}
```

My updated document is like:

```
{
Canditate:"Clark weg",
Location:"California",
Education:"Graguate"
Match_Tasks:[{Asignee:"Mike@gmail.com", 
        Task_ID's:
            [
            {ID:"ObjectID_(2)"}
            ]
        },
{Asignee:"Scarlett@gmail.com", 
        Task_ID's:
            [
            {ID:"ObjectID_(3)"}
            ]
        }
}
```

3 rd and 4th reponses:
Third response:

```
{
Asignee:"Mike@gmail.com",
Task_ID:"ObjectID_(1)"
}
```

Fourth response:

```
{
Asignee:"Scarlett@gmail.com",
Task_ID:"ObjectID_(2)"
}
```

My updated document after my 3 rd and 4 th response:

```
{
Canditate:"Clark weg",
Location:"California",
Education:"Graduate"
Match_Tasks:[{Asignee:"Mike@gmail.com", 
        Task_ID's:
            [
            {ID:"ObjectID_(1)"},
            {ID:"ObjectID_(2)"}
            ]
        },
        {{Asignee:"Scarlett@gmail.com", 
        Task_ID's:
            [
            {ID:"ObjectID_(3)"},
            {ID:"ObjectID_(2)"}
            ]
        }
}
```

I am trying with the pymongo code:

```
aggregate([{"$match":{"Canditate":"Clark weg"}},{"$set":{"Match_Tasks":{
                                        "$map": {
                                    "input": "$Match_Tasks",
                                        "as": "Match_Tasks",
                                        "in": 
                                                        {"$cond":[{"$eq":["$Match_Tasks.Asignee",Asignee]},
                                                        {"$push":{"Match_Tasks.$.Task_ID's":{"$ID":Task_ID}}},
                                                        {"$push":{"Match_Tasks":{"Asignee":email,"Task_ID's":[{"$ID":Task_ID}]}}}]}}}} }])
```

Comment: One option here is to use an aggregation pipeline with a `$merge` step at the end

Comment: I have posted my query, I have tried but getting error:"set" has no attribute push.Could you please help me?